# How do you even out textboxes?

Tags: html, web

I have two textboxes that I want to even out. By even out, I mean this:

```
[text] --> < input type="text" / >

[More more text] --> < input type="text" / >
```

I want the two "inputs" to be inline with each other. How do I move the first input text box to match the position of the second one which is pushed further due to the "more more text".

Comment: Also, read any CSS tutorial. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two bits of text are labels for the input fields, right?

You can enclose them in a `<label>` tag, like so:

```
<label for='field1'>Some text</label><input type='text' id='field1' /><br />
<label for='field2'>Some more text</label><input type='text' id='field2' /><br />
```

Then use CSS styles to fix them to a set width, like so:

```
label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
}
```

This should make your input fields line up.

There's a whole bunch of other ways to do it, but I'll leave you with that one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For people unfamiliar with the label element, clicking it focuses the form field – a win for usability.

Comment: Indeed, as @Rich says, the question could have been answered just as easily with `<span>`, but `<label>` is the best choice element for this because this is exactly what it was designed for, and you get the usability bonus for free.

Answer (score -2):

Use a table element:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text box</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Even more text</td>
    <td>Text box</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8PK/)**

Comment: Remember that joke answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: @RichBradshaw: If the data is tabular in nature (which may easily be the case here), why *not* use a table?

Comment: There is no indication that the data is tabular. In fact, it looks like a form with labels and boxes – definitely not a good candidate for a table.